# C++ Pistache Middleware

Tags: c++

I am attempting to add middleware to Pistache.
Here is my Routes:

```
RoutesManager::RoutesManager(Address addr) : Http::Endpoint(addr)
{
    Routes::Get(RoutesManager::router, "/token", Routes::bind(&JwtController::mintJwt));
    Routes::Get(RoutesManager::router, "/customers", Routes::bind(&CustomerController::getCustomer));

    router.addMiddleware(Routes::middleware(&JwtController::verifyJwt)); // <-- HERE
    //                     ^--- !!!Error HERE!!!
}
```

The error that I am getting is: `no instance of overloaded function "Pistache::Rest::Routes::middleware" matches the argument listC/C++(304) routes.cpp(9, 26): argument types are: (bool (RoutesManager::*)(Pistache::Http::Request &request, Pistache::Http::ResponseWriter &response))`

VerifyJwt looks like this:

```
bool verifyJwt(const Rest::Request& req, Http::ResponseWriter res)
        {
// Fun stuff
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: is verifyJwt a member function? If so the signature doesnt match

Comment: I have attempted a few different signatures, all seem to give me this very same error. To make things worse. There doesn't seem to be any good documentation for this. That is why I figured a question would be good to help me, and possibly others.
It seems like it may be a bad question, I will probably remove it.

Comment: you didnt answer the question. the casing of the function name strongly suggests it is a member function of a class - is it?

Comment: I have also attempted to use simply ```bool``` as is shown in a unit test found here https://github.com/pistacheio/pistache/pull/779/commits/08f23de67055c49a43881112bf5daeb972aaeeb3 It is the closest to an example as I could find. however, it still does not work. I think I do not understand enough to get this to work. I do believe that is what you are asking. Any ideas about how I may be able to fix this?

Comment: Is the function verifyJwt part of a class? Thats what I am asking, the error you are getting will occur if that is the case. It needs a free-standing function

Comment: @pm100 Thank you! Moving the function outside of the class was correct, Then I also had to call: ```this->setHandler(router.handler());``` from within the class. The middleware runs every request now. Thank you very much! I am still learning this, I will work to figure out what exactly is going on.

Comment: the actual signature of a member function includes an extra first arg that is the 'this' pointer, thats why it didnt match

Comment: @pm100, if you add this a the answer, I can accept it, I will also add my working solution to the bottom of my question incase anyone else may be new like me and need direction.